# Spring application can't retrieve data from property source

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to retrieve data from application.properties file using Environment in my Spring Application but it's not working. I cant get the data bound correctly by Environment. I only can get this working if I use local variables as shown below:

AppConfig.class now!

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.victommasi.eshop.dao")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class AppConfig {

private static final String driverClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/eshop";
private static final String username = "root";
private static final String password = "root";

private static final String dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect";
private static final String showSql = "true";
private static final String formatSql = "true";
private static final String hbm2dllAuto = "update";
private static final String packageToScan = "com.victommasi.eshop.model";


@Bean 
public DataSource dataSource(){
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClass);
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUsername(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);   
    return dataSource;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", showSql);
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", formatSql);
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hbm2dllAuto);
    return properties;        
}


@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();     
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject()); 
    return transactionManager;

}

@Bean 
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProvider(new HibernatePersistenceProvider());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(packageToScan);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

 }
```

AppConfig.class as I want

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.victommasi.eshop.dao")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class AppConfig {

@Autowired
private Environment env;


@Bean 
public DataSource dataSource(){
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClass"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));   
    return dataSource;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    return properties;        
}


@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();     
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject()); 
    return transactionManager;

}

@Bean 
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProvider(new HibernatePersistenceProvider());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("packages.to.scan"));
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}
```

Other classes:

WebConfig.class

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.victommasi.eshop" })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}

@Bean(name = "filterMultipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver getMultipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(1048576);
    multipartResolver.setMaxInMemorySize(1048576);
    return multipartResolver;
}

 }
```

WebAppInitializer.class

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(WebConfig.class, AppConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class);

    container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServlet = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    dispatcherServlet.register(WebConfig.class);

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServlet));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");
}

}
```

I know it seems to be a very easy, I have also followed this [tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/), but cant get this done.

Comment: Please describe _it's not working_. Is the call to `getProperty` returning `null`? Is Spring throwing an exception? What do you expect to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: Sorry for not describing it well. After reading your comment I took a look at console and found that data in 'application.properties' file were binded with blank spaces and I assume it was the reason the binding wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't go through it all but it seems like you're missing the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean

> Since Spring 3.1 introduced the new @PropertySource annotation, as a
>   convenient mechanism of adding property sources to the environment.
>   This annotation is to be used in conjunction with Java based
>   configuration and the @Configuration annotation:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class AppConfig {
   @Bean
   public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
      return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
   }
}
```

With that, you can now start injecting a property with the `@Value` annotation is straightforward:

```
@Value( "${jdbc.url}" )
private String jdbcUrl;
```

On the other note, consider/look into [spring-boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) ,  you'll get all the above (including all the code you have shared)and much more out for free i.e with zero line of code

Comment: Thanks, but I'd would like to use Environment as it is the recommended by Spring.

Comment: Not sure which spring you're referring to, but all the best

Answer (score 0):

After reading a comment I took a look at console and found that data in 'application.properties' file were binded to AppConfig.class by Environment with blank spaces.

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root      '@'localhost'
```

I assume it was the reason the binding wasn't working. My application is now working as I wanted. Thanks.